# Parsing XML Attributes

Tags: sql, xml, parsing

The following is an example of the XML I am attempting to parse:

```
<question-multichoice id="s2q1" name="">
  <text lang="en">How many medications are you taking?
</text>
  <options>
    <option id="19DEC09B9F" selected="false">
      <text lang="en">0 medications</text>
    </option>
    <option id="899D0E0798" points="1" selected="true">
      <text lang="en">1 medication</text>
    </option>
    <option id="E1315F7EDA" points="2" selected="false">
      <text lang="en">2 medications</text>
    </option>
    <option id="246B1927E8" points="3" selected="false">
      <text lang="en">3+ medications</text>
    </option>
  </options>
</question-multichoice>
```

I need to return the text string for example "1 medication" only where the attribute 'selected' is true.

I've got the following selection:

```
SELECT T3.loc3.value('options[1]', 'varchar(3000)') as response
```

And the following cross apply:

```
cross apply qa.XmlData.nodes('//section') as T2(Loc)
cross apply T2.Loc.nodes('./elements/child::*') as T3(loc3)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can pick out the element with some xpath:

```
declare @xml xml
set @xml =
'<question-multichoice id="s2q1" name="">
    <text lang="en">How many medications are you taking?</text>
    <options>
        <option id="19DEC09B9F" selected="false">
            <text lang="en">0 medications</text>
        </option>
        <option id="899D0E0798" points="1" selected="true">
            <text lang="en">1 medication</text>
        </option>
        <option id="E1315F7EDA" points="2" selected="false">
            <text lang="en">2 medications</text>
        </option>
        <option id="246B1927E8" points="3" selected="false">
            <text lang="en">3+ medications</text>
        </option>
    </options>
</question-multichoice>'

-- get the option element that has the selected attribute set to "true"
select @xml.value('(/question-multichoice/options/option[@selected="true"]/text)[1]', 'nvarchar(100)')
```